# BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'user'

Tags: python, flask, 400-bad-request

im stuck with this problem
"werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'user' " and i cant keep going

app.py:

```
@app.route("/registrarse", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registrarse():
    usuario_nuevo = User(
        name_user=request.form["user"],
        password_user=request.form["password"],
        admin_user=False)
    db.session.add(usuario_nuevo)
    db.session.commit()
    return render_template("index.html")
```

registrarse.html:

```
<form action="/registrarse" method="post">

  <div class="form-floating mb-3">

     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" name="user" placeholder="Usuario">

        <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-floating mb-3">

     <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contraseña" name="password"
placeholder="Contraseña">
        <label for="contraseña">Contraseña</label>
  </div>

  <br><br>
   <div class="d-grid">

      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-login text-uppercase fw-bold" type="submit">
           
          Registrarse
      </button>
</form>
```

I tried doing request.form.get("user") and returns me "None", same with "password". I looked videos and forums but i can`t understand why im getting this error. Please help me :c

Comment: I think these values are only set for POST requests, but your route handles GET and POST.